# Create full set from a list with missing keys in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, key-value

I've done a lot of digging and I can't seem to find an answer to this particular problem; answers to similar problems, but nothing quite like this.

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is add missing keys with default values in a list. I have a List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() with the below structure:

### Key : Value

```
a : Apple
b : Orange
c : Mango
b : Lime
c : Lemon
a : Berry
d : Carrot
```

From the above list, I would like to create a complete set with missing keys in that set.

**Expected Output**

### Expected Key : Value

```
a : Apple
b : Orange
c : Mango
d : ""
a : ""
b : Lime
c : Lemon
d : ""
a : Berry
b : ""
c : ""
d : Carrot
```

Is it possible to do this in a performative way using C#?

Comment: Is it possible that you forgot to mention some sort of sequence logic? It looks like your keys are used more than once.

Comment: What do you mean by doing it 'faster'?

Comment: I guess Hayden has understood the question. It's a list manipulation using C# question, don't think any seqeunce logic required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Given**

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a", "Apple"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("b", "Orange"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("c", "Mango"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("b", "Lime"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("c", "Lemon"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a", "Berry"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("d", "Carrot"),
};
```

We're able to do this easily with a for-loop by doing the following. The below will get the distinct keys in the list.

```
var distinctKeys = list
    .Select(pair => pair.Key)
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(pair => pair)
    .ToArray();
```

If you're wanting to hardcode the `distinctKeys` directly and save on computing the distinct keys, you can do the following:

```
var distinctKeys = new[] {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
```

And the following loop will insert pairs  at the given index if it needs to fill in a key.

```
var lastKeyIndex = -1;

for (var index = 0; index < list.Count; index++)
{
    var currentKeyIndex = lastKeyIndex + 1 == distinctKeys.Length ? 0 : lastKeyIndex + 1;
    var currentKey = distinctKeys[currentKeyIndex];

    if (list[index].Key != currentKey)
    {
        list.Insert(index, new KeyValuePair<string, string>(currentKey, string.Empty));
    }

    lastKeyIndex = currentKeyIndex;
}

for (var index = lastKeyIndex; index < distinctKeys.Length; index++)
{
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(distinctKeys[index], string.Empty));
}
```

**Output**

```
a : Apple
b : Orange
c : Mango
d :
a :
b : Lime
c : Lemon
d :
a : Berry
b :
c :
d : Carrot
```

Comment: Thanks, Hayden, very close. But It didn't work for the below data:   a : Apple
b : Orange
c : Mango
a : Berry
b : Plum

Comment: If the last key(s) is not present, it's ignoring it and not putting the empty values. e.g. a : Apple b : Orange c : Mango a : Berry  also won't work

Comment: @DaemonBee See my edit.

Comment: @DaemonBee Will need more information on why it doesn't work.

Comment: apologies didn't work the edit. apologies didn't work the edit. few things noted for different sets: Set 1 `ca : Apple
ac : Mango
vb : Lime
ac : Lemon
ca : Berry` not working. Set 2 `ca : Apple vb : Plum
ac : Mango
vb : Lime
ac : Lemon
ca : Berry` not working.

Comment: Actual Key,Value pair

`{[contacts.coid, 2003984]}
{[createdon, 2020-09-10]}
{[c_id, fcd5937d]}
{[contacts.coid, 2024489]}
{[createdon, 2020-09-10]}
{[contacts.fullname, Mark]}
{[c_id, 7e70096e]}
{[contacts.coid, 2024496]}
{[createdon, 2020-09-10]}
{[contacts.fullname, Simon]}
{[c_id, ebbbd1f4]}`

Expected 

`contacts.coid, 2003984
createdon, 2020-09-10
contacts.fullname, ""
c_id, fcd5937d
contacts.coid, 2024489
createdon, 2020-09-10
contacts.fullname, Mark
c_id, 7e70096e
contacts.coid, 2024496
createdon, 2020-09-10
contacts.fullname, Simon
c_id, ebbbd1f4`

Comment: on the above set the current logic is creating incorrect sets

Comment: @DaemonBee The code posted above works for the use cases. You'll need to define the distinctKeys manually or alter the original code for the distinctKeys order by with a custom comparator.

Comment: @DaemonBee It's also not appreciated to remove the green tick for this answer when the code posted above works for the input you've entered (and works for other inputs, just needs slight modification).